# How dynamically change the permissions of a text channel Discord.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am writing a small bot that will allow users in a voice channel to see a channel meant for people with no mics, then delete the channel afterwards.

I am able to make it see the people in a voice channel, but I am unable to create a channel which has the `PermissionsBitField.Flags.ViewChannel` set to "deny", to "allow" after the channel is created.
I have members as an object and interaction from a slash command.

```
async function restrictAccess(interaction, listeningMembers) {
    listeningMembers.forEach(member => {
        interaction.channel.permissionOverwrites.set([
            {
                id: member.user.id,
                allow: [PermissionsBitField.Flags.ViewChannel],
            }
        ]);
    });
}
```

I don't know if I am writing it incorrectly or if I need to do something else after I check the users in the voice channel (I check the users in the voice channel whenever someone speaks, not the most optimized but whatever)

Answer (score 0):

In your case, permissionOverwrites.set() only allows one user to view the channel

Use permissionOverwrites.edit() instead, i.e.

```
interaction.channel.permissionOverwrites.edit(member.user.id, { ViewChannel: true });
```

[discordjs docs](https://discordjs.dev/docs/packages/discord.js/main/PermissionOverwrites:Class#edit)